# How to create "calculate" button?

Tags: javascript, button, delay

I have a webpage that uses some variables that take a few seconds to be calculated.
I want to create a text field where it can be shown the sum of those 2 variables, but the problem is that that text field has to delay a bit (1-2 seconds). I've tried with " document.write(var1 + var2) " inside the specific function, but when the sum is ready, the page dissapear and it shows me only the result ( I want the result to appear in the same page ). I've also tried with "setTimeout" and I've obtained the same result ( only the sum appears on a new page)

I can also use a button that makes the delay and works fine ( I know how to do that, but I dont know how to display it ), I want the result to appears on a text field on the same page, or as any text. I've seen buttons that converts itselfs into the result when pressed bue again I dont know how to do it
Can anyone help me please ?
Thank you !

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: are you using jquery at all?

Comment: I dont have the code, only the variables that takes 1 sec to be calculated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if this is your text field.

```
<input type="text" id ="myinput">
```

insert value into it using this

```
document.getElementById("myinput").value=11233;
```

similarly for inserting text in any text field add an id and insert using  `getElementById`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your text field looks like this:

```
<span id='outputfield'>the result should appear here</span>
```

... then, use the following javascript code to update it after 2 seconds:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById('outputfield').innerHTML="Your result";
}, 2000);
```

If you are using jQuery, the inner line above may be shortened to just:

```
$('#outputfield').html("Your result");
```

Comment: Since you mentioned that you are using jQuery - `$("#outputfield").html(var1+var2);`. BTW, you don't need jQuery if you are doing just this calculation